# Define collectionView per collectionView.tag

Tags: ios, swift, tags, uicollectionview

I want to edit a cell in a collectionView, however because this is a nested collectionView there are multiple instances of it.

So say we have indexPath [0, 1] then the line of code below will set the cell as the first cell in each instance of the collectionView.

```
if let cell = self?.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? myCustomCell {
```

So anything i do here will be done to indexOath [0, 1] in all instances of collectionView.

You can put data into the cells in any instance of the collectionView with collectionView.tag:

```
cell.image.image = myArray[collectionView.tag][indexPath.item].image
```

But how can i define the collectionView as per its tag so i can singularly access that instance.  I cant figure out the syntax for some ideal situation like this:

```
let myCVInstance = self?.collectionView.tag(1)
if let cell = myCVInstance.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? myCustomCell {
```

So that we only access the first instance of the nested collectionView.

Thanks for tips

Answer (score 0):

Dumbest question ive asked..

Just need to check the tag number then if its the one you want do stuff:

```
if self?.collectionView.tag == myTag {
// do stuff
}
```